# How do you get Rails to use the LONGBLOB column in mysql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a migration that adds a LONGBLOB column to a table in a MySQL database.  I'd like to use LONGBLOB instead of BLOB so that I can store more data in the binary column.  The problem is that it adds a BLOB column even though I specify a larger size.

Here's the line I'm using to add the column:

```
add_column :db_files, :data, :binary, :null => false, :size => 1.megabyte
```

Am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The following will create a MEDIUMBLOB field. Use 16.megabyte to go to a LONGBLOB.

```
def self.up
  create_table "blob_test", :force => true do |t|
    t.column :data, :binary, :limit => 10.megabyte
  end
end
```

Comment: FYI, altering a `:binary` column in attempting to increase its size (changing a regular BLOB to a LONGBLOB) does not seem to work, if done via the Rails migration API (as of Rails 2.3.5).

Comment: Actually, that may not be true...  I think I may have been using the wrong parameter -- `:size` instead of `:limit`...  But I went ahead and used raw SQL via `execute`.  Note that, the original poster used the latter name (for specifying `1.megabyte`), while `:limit` seems to be the correct parameter (as given in the answer above).

Comment: Altering an existing blob to increase its size does seem to work with rails 4.1.  But make sure you specify the column type as :binary and not :blob.  If you specify it as :blob, even with a large :limit, you just get a blob.  With :binary and a large :limit you get a longblob.  E.g. "change_column :mytable, :mycolumn, :binary, :limit => 16.megabyte"

Answer (score -4):

class Migration_create_technologe extends CI_Migration {

```
public function up()
{
    $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
        'id' => array(
            'type' => 'INT',
            'constraint' => 11,
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
            'auto_increment' => TRUE
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '100',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        ),
        'writer' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '100',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        ),
        'created' => array(
            'type' => 'datetime',
             'default'=> '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            ),                           
    ));
    $this->dbforge->add_key('id',TRUE);
   $this->dbforge->add_field("body longblob NOT NULL ");
    $this->dbforge->create_table('technologe');
}

public function down()
{
    $this->dbforge->drop_table('technologe');
}
}
```