# Getting a binary limit from a migration to the schema in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mariadb, rails-migrations

I have a migration for a model with a binary field meant to store a file that can be bigger than 10Mb:

```ruby
class CreateNewModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :new_model do |t|
      ...
      t.binary :data, limit: 16777216
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

With the limit information the migration can create a longblob object in a MySQL or MariaDB database, as seen in [How do you get Rails to use the LONGBLOB column in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579536/how-do-you-get-rails-to-use-the-longblob-column-in-mysql).

The migration seems to work fine on a MariaDB database: data has longblob type. However loading directly from the schema gives data a blob type instead of longblob, this means the rake db:setup command is no longer usable as the schema doesn't reflect the database I want.

This seems pretty evident when one looks at the `db/schema.rb` file:

```ruby
create_table "new_model", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.binary   "data"
  ...
  t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
end
```

There is no limit info and as such loading the schema can only lead to blobs and not longblobs.

Why doesn't the limit information get written in the schema?

I don't want to change the schema manually as it would mean have to redo the change at each migration (as they regenerate the schema file). What other solutions do I have, is there a way to force the limit field from the migration to the schema?

I've tried using the shorthands described in https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21688 but it doesn't seem to exist in Rails 4.2.6.

Comment: You may find that big files are better left as files.  What will you be doing with the file?  Is it a video or some other media?

Comment: @RickJames : It's mostly images or PDFs that need to be stored somewhere, there is only a limited number of them per user and they are size limited (shouldn't be bigger then 15Mb). The way my code & stack is I only need to backup the database which I find very helpfull.